# Animated GIF stops working after opening and saving in Photoshop

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, graphics, gif, animated-gif

When I open [this animated GIF image](http://www.abelalarm.co.uk/images/loader.gif) in Photoshop and save it as GIF it stops working (rotating). I see about 6 layers. Do I have to do something with those layers? I'm really not getting this. I Googled but nobody seems to have this problem.

Comment: It may help if you could provide the version of Photoshop you are using.

Comment: @Bob version 6.2

Comment: *Version* 6.2? Not CS6, which is version 13? I'm not even sure if a version that old supports animations... and I vaguely remember PS 7 requiring ImageReady for Save for Web functionality. The CS6 version (which I'm on now) actually shows the animation timeline along the bottom in the default view.

Comment: @Bob sorry I misread from system info...Its actually version 12: `Adobe Photoshop Version: 12.0 (12.0x20100407 [20100407.r.1103 2010/04/07:14:00:00 cutoff; r branch]) x64
Operating System: Windows NT
Version: 6.2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select `Save for Web` in the `File` menu. A normal save will just give you a static image. Save for Web allows animated GIFs.

You can also open the animation editor (`Timeline` under the `Window` menu on CS6, but I think it was `Animation` under the same menu on older versions) to take a look at the animation sequence. Typically, each frame of the animation toggles one or more layers on and off (in fact, I think that's all it does).

Comment: Thank you. I noticed the "Save for Web" but it still doesn't work for me..Maybe its the modification Im doing: `1.`I select the background(by color range) `2.`I substract the background by "cut from layer and make new layer" `3.`I remove the new made layer `4.`Now the original layer has a transparent background instead of white. When I save for web it works, but when I repeat the above for all the layers it stops working. So this is what I don't get..

Comment: So basicly I need a transparent background instead of the white

Comment: @Youss I've just tried myself (my preferred method is removing the white using either the magic eraser or wand, with 0 tolerance and discontiguous). There was no problem retaining the animation. Note that you may lose animation if you fiddle with the layers (even just changing layer visibility), which you will need to reset with the `Window` > `Timeline` option.

Comment: @Youss Unfortunately, I'm having trouble getting Photoshop to redraw the background, so there's traces being left from the previous frame (and the anti-aliasing looks a but ugly), but here's a sample: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DULcC.gif

Comment: @Youss Ah, there we go! Just right click all frames in the timeline and select `Dispose`. The quality could use some work, but here it is: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LxM1W.gif - some dithering could fix the jagged edges, but that's not too effective if you don't know what the background colour will be. (the transparency for some reason does not work on Firefox's grey image background, but it's fine with an actual background)

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH:) (Why do things have to be so complicated..)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a frequent Photoshop user and I don't exactly know how it behaves, but it is perfectly normal that it displays a set of different layers: an animated GIF is nothing more than an image composed of different layers, each one of them representing a frame of the animation; you don't' have to think about it as a video file: even if it is an animation, it is still an image.
So, by opening (and modifying) it with a graphic editor, it is normal that you see a set of frames; to edit the animation, you will have to manually edit each one of them.

And I think that it should be treated like an animation from the beginning, I.E. not opening it (and subsequently editing and saving it) in the defualt way like an image, but like an animation; I don't exactly know how Photoshop handles this feature, but just [googling it](https://www.google.com/search?q=photoshop%20animated%20gifs) gives you a huge amount of guides guides about modifying animated GIFs:

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-Animated-GIFs-Using-Photoshop

http://creativetechs.com/tipsblog/build-animated-gifs-in-photoshop/

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/quick-photoshop-cs5-tutorial-create-animated-gifs/

Answer (score -1):

If you have a different problem from the one listed, it could be that you have the layers all visible at the same time on every single frame. You will have to go to each individual frame and toggle the layers you want visible for each frame.